# Add custom font mpdf-laravel

Tags: php, laravel, mpdf

I have a problem in adding a custom font to generated pdf .I used mpdf package and I did all the steps the add a custom font .I created a pdf.php in config folder with the code below

```
<?php

return [
    'custom_font_dir' => base_path('resources/fonts/'), // don't forget the trailing slash!
    'custom_font_data' => [
        'circular-black' => [
            'R'  => 'CircularStd-Black.otf',    // regular font

        ]
        // ...add as many as you want.
    ]
];
```

and in my controller

```
use PDF;

class pdfController extends Controller
{
public function generateResultat($id){


    $resultat=some data;

    $fileName='Resultat Order-'.$resultat->order->examCodeSession.'.pdf';
    $mpdf= new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'mode' => 'utf-8',
        'format' => 'A4',
        'margin_left'=>10,
        'margin_right'=>10,
        'margin_top'=>15,
        'margin_bottom'=>20,
        'margin_header'=>10,
        'margin_footer'=>10,

    ]);

    $html=\View::make('pdf.resultat',[
        'resultat'=>$resultat

    ]);
    $html->render();

    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output($fileName,'D');



}
```

}

Comment: Add custom font to `new \Mpdf\Mpdf([` array.

Comment: I added them in new \mpdf but it didn't work

Comment: @moaadbenazzouz did you place ttf font under mpdf\mpdf\ttfonts ?